# Civilization 6 not recognizing Nvidia graphics card + performance issues with steam

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, graphics, steam

Just installed Ubuntu 18.04.3 on a new box with the following specs:

**CPU**: Ryzen 9 3900X

**RAM:** 64GB

**GPU**: Nvidia RTX 2070 Super

I was planning on installing Steam and Civilization 6, as they both seem to be explicitly supported on Ubuntu, but I'm having a few issues.

I installed the Nvidia drivers (tried both `nvidia-driver-440` and `nvidia-drier-435`) and launched Civilization. To my surprise, the only in-game option for GPU Selection was labeled "Unknown Device" and the performance I'm getting out of the game (frames are dropping in simple background UI animations and the game completely freezes when I try to join a game with my friend) leads me to believe that the game is maybe using integrated graphics. A handful of Reddit threads and Stack Exchange posts have noted similar issues, however many are several years old and either unanswered or ambiguously answered.

I've also noticed some issues with the Steam app itself: occasionally freezing with a pointing cursor where I cannot click anything and have to force kill it.

Has anyone encountered or resolved issues with Steam or Civilization 6 as I have described above? Below is the output of `lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"` and I can edit anymore details that may be needed.

```
2d:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1ec7 (rev a1)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device 13aa
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't go with a later 18.04 (.2 or .3 with HWE enabled? as beyond the later kernel, it contains later X/graphics stack)  *Note: I'm not a gamer so there could be a reason I'm not aware of*

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, it is the .3